# cannot resolve method setImageBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapimage, android-bitmap

I want to display retrieved image from **MySQL** to android `imageView(image)`, but  get `cannot resolve method setImageBitmap` **error** .

```
  private void showStaff(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            String type = c.getString(Config.TAG_TYPE).trim();
            RetrieveType(type);
            String Description = c.getString(Config.TAG_DESCRIPTION).trim();
            String Amount=c.getString(Config.TAG_AMOUNT).trim();
            String image=c.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE);
            byte[] data= Base64.decode(image,0);
            Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
            image.setImageBitmap(b);  // error 
            description.setText(Description);
            amount.setText(Amount);
            // noH.setText(hours);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

how could I resolve this?

Comment: `image` is a String ?

Comment: @DidierAupest I retrieved it from MySQL

Comment: @DidierAupest I know what's wrong here..My imageView named image too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here image is a String so there is no method  setImageBitmap for Strings ,you need and ImageView to call setImageBitmap

Answer (score 1):

the image in:
 String image=c.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE);
is a string, so you cannot setImageBitmap(). may be scope problems ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem it is because of not proper casting
This worked for me

```
View mImg =findViewById(R.id.image_from_gallery);

((ImageView) mImg).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Try including more details about the problem in your answer.